# Will unsaved NSSet members in an NSManagedObject persist the removed members on save?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I ran into an interesting question from a colleague today. The answer seemed straightforward at first, but then I realized I had never seen any documentation to back up my assumption.

Given an `NSManagedObject` such as `Person` which has a one-to-many relationship with another object, such as `Friends`, and the code below -- will `friend1` and `friend2` be persisted to the data store?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [a private context];
Person *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSMutableSet *friendsSet = [NSMutableSet new]; 
// Create some friends in the private context
Person *aFriend1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friend"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
[friendsSet addObject:friend1];
Person *aFriend2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friend"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
[friendsSet addObject:friend2];

// Add these friends to aPerson
[person addFriends:friendsSet];

// Alas! aPerson decides they want better friends.
NSMutableSet *betterFriendsSet = [NSMutableSet new]; 

Person *aFriend3 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friend"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
[betterFriendsSet addObject:friend3];
Person *aFriend4 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friend"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
[betterFriendsSet addObject:friend4];

// Dump those old friends
aPerson.friends = nil;
// Add the new friends
[person addFriends:betterFriendsSet];

// Save 
[context save:nil];
```

Does aPerson have 2 friends or 4 in the data store? My assumption would be 2, since there are no longer any strong references to friend1 and friend2, they should be released. However, the core data generated accessors may be doing more behind the scenes and hold a strong reference to them, in which case they would be persisted to the data store.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually asking two different things:

> will friend1 and friend2 be persisted to the data store?

Yes. You added them to the managed object context and then saved changes. Whether they get saved is not affected by whether they're related to `aPerson`. This doesn't have anything to do with generated accessors, it's just that you added them to the context and never removed them. If you don't want to keep them, you need to delete them.

> Does aPerson have 2 friends or 4 in the data store?

It has two. Since you set `friends` to `nil`, you removed the relationship for the first two friend instances. When your code above finishes, `aPerson` has two friends. The previous friends are still in the persistent store, but they are no longer related to any `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start, the supplied Core Data methods to add and remove set members for a Core Data property is (example property is "Ratings"):
Add a single member

```
- (void)addRatingsObject:(RatingsDB *)value;
- (void)removeRatingsObject:(RatingsDB *)value;
```

Add a set of members

```
- (void)addRatings:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeRatings:(NSSet *)value;
```

Next, the method insertNewObjectForEntityForName will create the Core Data objects for "Friend" and they will persist with a save no matter what you do with NSSet contents.  They will just become unlinked from the "Person" entity created with the nil.

You will have four "Friend" records when completed as described.